# Access - Searching through two identical table structures

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I currently have two identical tables (As far as columns) in my access database. I setup a form that allows a user to enter an ID and search through ONE of the tables.

I am trying to have it search through a second table as well, but my query doesn’t return results from BOTH tables. I am only able to retrieve results from the first table.

I used query design to build my query which was basically just selecting the table I need and bringing down all the fields in the criteria section. When I tried to build the second query, I selected both tables and matched the ID’s from both tables, but the results were not correct (ID existed in both tables, but only showed ID from one table).

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()        
    If Nz(comboID, "") <> "" Then
        'DoCmd.OpenQuery "Inquiries Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
         DoCmd.OpenQuery "both tables", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
    Else
      '  If Nz(txtReportDate, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "NOTICE! Please enter a ID"
        Exit Sub

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show using comboID? If you're joining on ID then yes it will only show one ID but they will be the same. Are you trying to show IDs that are in both tables - or either and both? Update your question with current SQL from `"both tables"`

Comment: @dbmitch The comboID is the search box. As they type in the first few numbers of theID, it autofills for the users. Yes, i am trying to show ID's from both tables. Both tables can hold the same ID but different status so i want it to show both.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a union all query.

```
"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = " & comboID.value & _
"UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ID = " & comboID.value & ";"
```

This would runs two separate select queries and combine all the columns that are the same.

Note: if you have the exact same record in both tables it will show up twice.

Comment: The `UNION` keyword automatically removes duplicate rows.  `UNION ALL` forces all records to be included even if they are duplicate.

Comment: You are correct, @CPerkins I must've put a decimal point in the wrong place or something, I always do that. I always mess up some mundane detail.